# Why is my for loop increasing the size of my array in C?

Tags: arrays, c, binary

I'm trying to make a binary number calculator in c and I'm running into issues of my for loops doubling the size of my second array and adding the first array onto the end. I'm really confused because I thought you couldn't increase the size after already declaring it. It is happening in my equation reading function as well but in this ones complement function it's a bit simpler to see. Any ideas of how to fix this?[the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwbmI.png)[the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7aycA.png)

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: You can use the `edit` button below your question to improve according to Adrian Mole's hints.

Comment: `puts` expects to receive the address of a valid C string. Your arrays are no strings as they lack the mandatory 0 terminator. Using invalid buffers invokes undefined behaviour. Also, the arrays cannot even hold the terminator due to lack of extra room for it.

Comment: Guesses: overflow with buffers that are too small, or failing to write a string terminator (or both).

Comment: Aside: the code does not need those `continue;` statements - the `if ... else` construct handles that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to stack-overflow. From next time please use inline code editor to put your code instead of images. I have taken effort put your code in the answer itself to explain the problem. Please consider this as courtesy. Its very unusual to do it. But as you are a new member, I'm doing it.

```
// Cole carson's original code from image:
char * onescomp(char x[16], char y[16]){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=15;i++){
        if(x[i] == '0'){
            y[i] = '1';
            continue;
        }
        else if(x[i] == '1'){
            y[i] = '0';
        continue;
        }
    }
    return y;
}
int main()
{
    char b3n[16]={'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'};
    char cb3n[16];
    puts(b3n);
    onescomp(b3n,cb3n);
    puts(cb3n);
    return 0;
}
```

**Answer:**

1. You don't need `continue;` in if-else blocks.
2. You need to add `'\0'` in the last cell of `cb3n` array. so `puts()` knows when string ends & stop printing.

so to quickly fix this issue you can create array with extra cell and assign all values as `'\0'`. so after copying fifteen 1's there will be `'\0'` in the end. I think in your case those extra zeros being printed might be garbage values. It looks like array is doubling but it isn't, its just printing values beyond allocated memory because `'\0'` has not been provided.

```
//Quick fix
int main()
{
    char b3n[16]={'0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0','0'};
    char cb3n[17]={'\0'}; // <--- quick fix
    puts(b3n);
    onescomp(b3n,cb3n);
    puts(cb3n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Mudassir, sorry about the code image. This worked and now both functions are working!

Comment: You can accept the answer if its working.

Comment: There is also a 0 byte missing in `b3n` array.

Comment: The exta ? `'0'` that were printed, are likely the whole array `b3n`